# Getting Detailed Part information

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

As an introduction I did some programming in college but that was about 13 years ago and I haven't had to do any since.  About 2 months ago my boss asked if I was interested in it and if I'd be willing to work on some "basic" problems the company has.  I said yes, and now I'm here.  What we are trying to do is take a list of Manufacturer part numbers and get detailed information from the internet using webscraping.  I tried to take this step by step.  First was well our data is in excel how do I get it to python to use it.  Through some self-learning apps and a basic course on python 3 I came up with the following:

```
wb=load_workbook(filename="Description.xlsx")
sheet=wb["MFG PN"]

mfgpn=[]
for col in sheet["A"]:
    mfgpn.append(col.value)
```

this part worked for me.  I now have a list of the mfg pn's that we have (about 30k) The rest of my code is using BeautifulSoup to try (i'm failing miserably) to create a table.  My code looks like this.

```
for html in range(len(mfgpn)):
    try:
        squirrel=urlopen("http://www.vyrian.com/parts.html?mfgPartNo="+str(mfgpn[html]))
        bsObj=BeautifulSoup(squirrel,"html.parser")
        Headers=[th.getText() for th in bsObj.findAll("tr", limit=2)[1].findAll('th')]
        Rows=bsObj.findAll('tr')
        PartData=[[td.getText() for td in Rows[i].findAll('td')] for i in range(len(Rows))]
        print(PartData)
    except:
        (AttributeError, TypeError, NameError)
        pass
```

Now I have tried several other approaches and have been unsuccessful, so to my question.  Is there a better approach to this problem then scraping tables.  I have been able to print out "long form" descriptions of all 30k part numbers.  We would like all the attributes of a part broken out so we can filter on them (packet size, resistance, capacitance, etc).  One approach I haven't looked into which I think maybe I should is to take the long form descriptions (which are basically just concatenated strings) and split each description into the parts we are looking for.

Anyways I signed up here hoping I could get a little direction, even if it's to scrap what I've done and try a different angle that would be fine.

I am not receiving an error with this code, What I am getting looks like this

> '-Frequency Stability Ppm-', '-'], ['-Minimum Operating Temperature C-Display Quantity-Frequency Stability Ppm-', '-Display Quantity-Frequency Stability Ppm-', '-Frequency Stability Ppm-', '-'], ['-Display Quantity-Frequency Stability Ppm-', '-Frequency Stability Ppm-', '-'], ['-Frequency Stability Ppm-', '-'], ['-']] -

This is obviously a very small portion of whats printed but it all tends to look like this.

I believe in the ['-'] should be the values I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If the data you need is only accessible through the website, then scraping it is the right option. I don't see any obvious errors in your code but you can probably debug it yourself by:

- using your browser tools to inspect the content of the page you want to scrap (right-click -> inspect)
- separate your code into functions and write some unit-tests to ensure each function does what you expect it to
- also note that beautiful soup may fail if there is some javascript involved (it's not the case here)

If you still can't get it working, you should at least detail the error/unexpected behaviour you get and for which URL (ideally a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), to get more specific answers.